# is there a way to compare a textbox input old and new in php during the form submit?

Tags: php

I have a form that will submit an email. 
The textbox is updated with the current email from the server when the form loads.

If the email gets changed on the form I want do something.
if the email does not get changed I want to do nothing.

Is this even possible in PHP?

```
<?php
//email value from sql database, value of textbox before changed.
$val = $emailVal;
//new value from textbox
$newVal = $updatedVal;

if($val != "" && $val != $newVal){
    echo('the textbox has changed');
    //now update firebase database
}else{
    echo('nothing has changed');
    //now do nothing
};
?>
```

So turns out I just needed to use $_SESSION to get the associate variable that was needed to compare.  Thanks for the help!

```
$_SESSION["oldEmail"] = $sql_data->get_field('email'); 
$oldEmail = $_SESSION["oldEmail"]; 

echo($_SESSION['oldEmail']);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, you need a reference copy and then use that to compare.

Run the db select statement, bring it into an associative array, and either stick that in a session variable or pull out the bits you want to be able to compare and put them into an associative array and stick that in a session variable.

Then on form submit, check form values, compare as desired with what is stored in the session variable, and take appropriate action.  Maybe after db updates, etc. you also update the session variable, so you can reference needed values on each page to customize the site for preferences, etc.

Comment: worked perfectly!  I had tried earlier to make this work using sessions but your answer made me rethink and try again.  Thanks, I now have it working!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can easily when submitting the form compare the value in database and the value in textbook if there are changes you can do what you need.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button'])){
$oldEmail =    getEmail(); 
if($_POST['email'] == $oldEmail){
// write your code
}
else { }
}

function getEmail(){
// write your sql query to get the email
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  problem I am having is that they will always match in this situation because the value changes and the database is updated at the same time so therefore, I hit the if all the time.

Comment: if i understand what you mean, i think you need to do this before update on database at the same function that do the update on database

Comment: yes.  I need to do this at the same time in the same function without going to a separate php file on another page.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I got the solution using $_SESSIONS as ivanivan suggested. Thanks again.